# ¿Como se integran entre si wordpress, prestashop, react/angular etc o son cosas totalmente separadas?

Tags: wordpress, prestashop, cms

el motivo de esta pregunta es porque desde hace tiempo estoy intentando centrarme más en el desarrollo de paginas web y he tenido pequeños trabajos en maquetación, y con javascript, aparte de haber hecho cursos hace ya bastante tiempo, el problema es que cuando hice dichos cursos no existia ni angular/react, wordpress no estaba tan extendido etc, entonces ahora tengo un poco de cacao porque aunque se y he trabajado un poco con por ejemplo Angular, no veo como se integran o relacionan entre si, y en muchas ofertas de trabajo veo que piden todas estas tecnologias como si fueran un todo, aunque no veo la relación.

Se que wordpress, por lo que he trabajado en drupal que no es mucho pero al menos algo es, es un gestor de contenido, basicamente trabajar con bloques, presupongo que se suele pedir wordpress y php para poder crear bloques personalizados, pero ya a partir de ahí empieza mi duda porque he consultado con un compañero que trabaja con wordpress y el me ha dicho que nunca programa nada, por lo que me deja un poco descolocado.

Además cuando busco información sobre como se integra wordpress con otras herramientas, como prestashop que casi toda oferta de trabajo lo tratan como un solo ente, muchos cursos hablan de ellos como dos cosas totalmente separadas, es decir no hablan por lo general de como se integran, entonces, ¿como interviene ahí prestashop?, que se supone es una especie de gestor pero para las compras.

Igualmente con entornos como react, angular etc, ¿son independientes a wordpress? ¿o puedes relacionarlas? digo porque react/angular normalmente se usan para node.js que es para usar un servidor con javascript, sin embargo wordpress al igual que drupal principalmente usa php, ¿es posible usar ambas o son formas distintas de trabajar?.

He buscado muchas veces información similar, pero no veo algo detallado que pueda ayudar a "viejos programadores" de web a entender como ha cambiado todo, suelo ver algo de información suelta por ejemplo alguien explicando usa el plugin de wordpress y prestashop y no me aclara si esa es la única forma de integración, y todo debe ir por plugins, si es otra forma diferente para obtener solo las herramientas basicas y no tener que integrar todo etc.

Comment: Wordpress como ya sabe es un sistema de gestión de contenido, pero usa React que es una biblioteca para su creador de páginas, hasta donde yo sé así existe esa relación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veras, tu amigo dice que no programa nada por que Wordpress permite instalar y personalizar "plugins", los plugins son herramientas para complementar las funcionalidades de un sitio. Ejemplo: Necesitas un boton que te lleve a las redes sociales, solo instalas uno de los plugins que existen para eso (hay varios para cada cosa), colocas, acomodas y listo. Por supuesto Wordpress tambien permite programar, puedes personalizar el sitio a un mas haciendolo o si no hubo ningun plugin que se ajustara a tus requerimientos, no es obligatorio usar solo plugins, solo es mas "sencillo"...

Trabajo con PrestaShop y hasta donde se, no se puede relacionar en nada de nada con Wordpress, digamos que Wordpress es un poco mas "libre" en lo que de diseño se trata, puedes insertarle código y todo, es perfecto para blogs. PrestaShop es mucho mas restrictivo, tu solo instalas, le agregas el tema deseado y listo, no te deja modificar nada mas (dependiendo del tema), desde el panel solo debes agregar precio, productos, etc, ya que es especializado para tiendas online, quizás si sabes lo que haces puedas ingresar a los archivos internos y modificarle el código, si realmente necesitas cambiarle el diseño a algo, pero es muy poco recomendable.

Así como Wordpress usa plugins, PrestaShop usa modulos (lo mismo solo que con otro nombre)...

En fin, relacionar Wordpress y PrestaShop juntos es como decir que vas relacionar Windows y Linux, Google y Microsoft o Play Station y Xbox(?)

Comment: Solo te explico la cuestión de Wordpress y PrestaShop por que de Angular/React no se nada...

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿en Prestashop también se puede programar para personalizar los modulos?, digo porque has comentado que es bastante restrictivo, no se si tiene algo de programación, o si al ser tan restrictivo es simplemente un instalalo, configuralo y punto porque no tienes mucho espacio por no decir ninguno para personalizar y si usa programación php como wordpress u otro tipo de programación para los modulos.

Comment: Hmm... En mi experiencia no te deja programar nada de nada, 0 programación, solo configuras lo que te permita el tema que tienes instalado en la tienda y listo. Tuve problemas con eso hace algunos meses, busque, hasta que di con un modulo que permitía insertarle/cambiarle codigo al CSS y Javascript ("CUSTOM CODE MODULE BY ST-THEMES") pero hasta ahí nomas

Comment: Aunque hay una comunidad de desarrolladores de PrestaShop, ellos desarrollan los módulos específicos para cada cosa. Ejemplo: Cuando mencione que tuve problemas para modificar algo en el código de la tienda, lo que necesitaba era cambiar de posición la descripción del producto y otras cosas, al investigar me topaba con módulos que servían para eso hecho por los desarrolladores que mencioné, pero eran de paga y no quise darme a la tarea de pedirle a mi jefe mas presupuesto así que opte por otras opciones...

Comment: El modulo del que hable "CUSTOM CODE MODULE BY ST-THEMES" también esta hecho por un grupo de desarrolladores de PrestaShop, lo que quiero decir, es que de programar, si puedes programar, pero no directamente en la tienda, programas módulos para funciones especificas... Incluso hay un manual para desarrollar en PrestaShop. Aqui hay un poco de mas informacion: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/265034-aprender-a-programar-en-prestashop/